# Why do I need a "bean:" prefix here?

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I'm trying to cope with Spring Security and I think I got it work so far but can somebody explain to me a few things here? In particular I would like to know why I need to use this `beans:` prefix in this configuration file:

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <beans:import resource="applicationContext-jooq.xml"/>

    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <http auto-config="true" >
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager >
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="admin" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <!-- BEGIN Services -->

    <beans:bean id="loginService" class="com.mz.server.web.service.LoginService">
        <beans:constructor-arg>
            <beans:ref bean="dsl" />
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- END Services -->

</beans:beans>
```

Another thing I'd like to understand is the difference between

```
<intercept-url pattern="/"   .. />
<intercept-url pattern="/*"  .. />
<intercept-url pattern="/**" .. />
```

Answer (score 0):

You mixxed up your xml-header where spring-security is your root-header now.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd"
   ........> </beans>
```

**Second Question:**

The difference between * and ** is that the * only describes the same folder, while ** is recursive. I am not sure about a / without regex, but i think it won't protect.

Comment: Hi! What exactly makes Spring Security my root header now? Or better: How is a root-header declared? By header you mean a bean-config-file, right?

Comment: Because its the one without an explicite declaration. See xmlns vs xmlns:beans. See: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp